# SQL Server Using sub query in JOIN statements

Tags: sql-server, subquery, query-optimization, join

Does JOINING of tables more easy to read or faster to execute if I create a sub query and a select statement with only the columns needed for the entire query?

```
-- Example
    SELECT s.Id,  
           s.TransactionDate, 
           s.TransactionNo,
           s.CustomerId,
           s.SiteLocationId,
           s.SubTotal,
           sd.ItemId,
           sd.UnitPrice,
           sd.GrossAmount
    FROM tblTransactions s
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTransactionDetails sd ON sd.TransactionId = s.Id
```

Compare to this:

```
SELECT s.Id, 
       s.TransactionDate, 
       s.TransactionNo,
       s.CustomerId,
       s.SubTotal,
       sd.ItemId,
       sd.UnitPrice,
       sd.GrossAmount
FROM tblTransactions s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                        SELECT TransactionId,
                               ItemId,
                               UnitPrice,
                               GrossAmount
                        FROM tblTransactionDetails
                    ) sd ON sd.TransactionId = s.Id
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each example given? I am also trying to reduce the percentage read of the Details in the Execution Plan.

Comment: This only makes the query more complicated than necessary. It is neither more readable nor should it in any way influence performance. Keep in mind that there is an optimizer analyzing your queries before running them. This optimizer will easily detect that the queries are equivalent. Stick with the first straight-forward query.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I just assume that since I don't need all the columns for the Details table maybe I can reduce the execution time of the query by only showing the specifics columns needed for the query.

Comment: @ZeroCool - the optimizer detects which columns you've used in the join predicate, the where clause or which ones are you selecting and based on that it's "pulling" only those columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think that SQL Server creates the same execution plan for both queries. If you want to increase the performance due to the column selection, you should create a non-clustered index. Then, the query optimizer should use the more compact index instead the table.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_tblTransactionDetails_test 
    ON tblTransactionDetails (TransactionId) INCLUDE (ItemId, UnitPrice, GrossAmount)
```